# How to give link to navigation menu on one item in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'am integrating a theme to wordpress. My theme is single page website.But now i want to add an additional page (blog.php) so I just wanted to know How can i give a link to one of my navigation menu item (blog) in wordpress. I simply wrote

```html
<li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
```

But the above code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you any menu location in the WP admin panel in "Appearance"? If you do, you can fill a menu with "Links" menu item in which you can place the URL like `/blog.php`. If you don't you can register a menu in functions.php and add it after `<body id="body" <?php body_class(); ?> >` in header.php file of your theme:

Add to functions.php:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_register_nav_menu' );
function theme_register_nav_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Menu' );
}
```

add to header.php:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

After you can create a new menu, place it in 'primary' location and fill it with arbitrary links of other pages.